# Wpf combobox selected item by mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox of text align buttons and when I try to choose one of them by mouse click, selected item doesn't change. It seems like ComboBoxItem doen't get Click event. Does any one know how to handle that?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FontAligmentCombo">
  <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
    <Button Command="EditingCommands.AlignLeft"
            ToolTip="Align Left">
        <Viewbox>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource icon8_Win10_AlignLeft}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
  </ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>
    <Button Command="EditingCommands.AlignCenter"
            ToolTip="Align Center">
        <Viewbox>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource icon8_Win10_AlignCenter}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
  </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
<Button Command="EditingCommands.AlignLeft"
        ToolTip="Align Left">
    <Viewbox>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource icon8_Win10_AlignLeft}" />
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

You hardcoded `IsSelected` to True. Try handling selected Items in Combobox itself by `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` property. In your case Index makes sense. If you cannot, you should bind the bool value.

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` "swallows" the click. You will have to select the corresponding `ComboBoxItem` programmatically.

Try this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FontAligmentCombo">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="OnClick" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">
        <Button Command="EditingCommands.AlignLeft" ToolTip="Align Left">
            <Viewbox>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource icon8_Win10_AlignLeft}" />
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <Button Command="EditingCommands.AlignCenter" ToolTip="Align Center">
            <Viewbox>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource icon8_Win10_AlignCenter}" />
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

---

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    ComboBoxItem cbi = FindParent<ComboBoxItem>(button);
    if (cbi != null)
    {
        FontAligmentCombo.SelectedItem = cbi;
        FontAligmentCombo.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
}
```